# How to filter results on _id column of elasticsearch?

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I want results to be filtered on _id column in elasticsearch.

for example - select * from table1 where _id not in ('1','2','3');

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky - My question is not clear to you,is it ?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky well if you know about elasticsearch then you should understand my query.There is _id column in elasticsearch index.How to filter results on _id column ?

Comment: Ok sorry then :) ill let others do the talking

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky did you downvoted,if yes why ?

Comment: Nope I didn't down-vote

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the request body then. For a curl like you showed, here's how to do:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/articles/_search?pretty' -d '
{
  "query": { "match_all": {} },
  "filter" : {
            "not" : {
                "ids" : {
                    "values" : ["evNeovIVRP6chF3hU-5rpA", "azvIVRP6chF3hU-5rpA", "another_id"]
                }
            }
        }
}'
```

Comment: yes i use query DSL...is it _id or id_ ? and also I cant use range as I have few specific ids which should not come in result.Any idea?

Comment: I am using a curl request - 

http://localhost:9200/articles/_search/?q=!_id:53e458e8bffebc00098b4567&size=3

this request is working fine,but what is the syntax for multiple ids like q=!_id:53e458e8bffebc00098b4567,e458e8bffebc00098b456123 ?

Comment: Seems you're using a request URI type. Try the updated response @arp

Comment: I tried your updated code with 1 id but that is returning all the documents.
my total documents 415,result with above code 415 . :(

Comment: Weird ! It'working with my installation there. Have you putted the id into double quotes ?